# How can I use a smaller schema, that has a reference, within a larger schema?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, schema

I am trying to create a smaller schema that I can re-use within a larger schema..

My 'users' schema is defined (in another file)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const noRights = require('../models/Roles').user_noRights;
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    // these are required to create a user
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true, lowercase: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    role: {type: String, required: true, default: noRights},
})
module.exports = User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema)
```

This works ( but it's not using the smaller "user" schema )

```
const PostSchema = new Schema({
  text: {type: String, required: true },
  date: {type: Date,default: Date.now},
  user: { 
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
      ref: 'users'
  }
});
```

Here is the smaller "user" schema I would like to employ:

```
const userData = new Schema({
  type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
  ref: 'users' 
});
```

The smaller "user" schema is used here, and it's failing:

```
const PostSchema = new Schema({
  text: {type: String, required: true },
  date: {type: Date,default: Date.now},
  user: { type: userData },
});
```

Here is the error

```
C:\GitHub\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:717
[0]     throw new TypeError('Undefined type `' + name + '` at `' + path +
[0]     ^
[0]
[0] TypeError: Undefined type `Users` at `ref`
[0]   Did you try nesting Schemas? You can only nest using refs or arrays.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using npm's "deepPopulate" module - very nice !